# Why this php regular expression program crash

Tags: php, regex, crash, expression

> here is the code

```
 <?php 
//here is the string
$str ="<style>
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
  .a{color: red;}
</style>";
$str=ycs($str);
function ycs($str){
    $str = preg_replace_callback("/<style>([^<])+<\/style>/is", function($matched){
      return "abc";
}, $str);
return $str;
}
echo $str;
?>
```

> like the code i write,the php program crash! But when i change the
>   code **"/([^<])+</style>/is"** to **"/[^<]+</style>/is"**
>   ,it can run again,Why?I use xampp.

Comment: [There is no crash](https://ideone.com/n6Nod8) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that you are capturing everything but a `<` a single time but your are repeating this operation multiple times by using the group causing an ugly regex operation (this shouldn't crash but you would have an ugly performance).

[image: Regular expression visualization]

So, you can change this:

```
<style>([^<])+<\/style>
```

To

```
<style>([^<]+)<\/style>
```

Above change will improve the regex by having the pattern repetition and then capturing the content, which I guess you wanted to do.

[image: Regular expression visualization]